# Rust Unzip with Fallible Mapping

Tags: rust

I have a fallible mapping over a vector that I want to modify to produce two vectors. My original mapping looked like this:

```rust
let result: Result<Vec<i32>, String> = list.iter().map(|elem| {
    let intermediate = fallible1(elem)?;
    Ok(fallible2(&intermediate)?)
}).collect();
```

Now I want to modify my code to also emit the intermediate result. For this I reached for the `unzip` function. However, since the unzip function doesn't deal with fallibility like the `collect` function can, I have to chain the two in an awkward way. I have reduced my code to a minimal reproducible example:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let fallible1 = |num: &i32| -> Result<i32, String> { Ok(num + 1) };
    let fallible2 = |num: &i32| -> Result<i32, String> { Ok(num + 2) };
    let list = [1, 2, 3];
    let (result, intermediate): (Vec<i32>, Vec<i32>) = list.iter().map(|elem| {
        let intermediate = fallible1(elem)?;
        Ok((fallible2(&intermediate)?, intermediate))
    }).collect::<Result<Vec<(i32, i32)>, String>>()?.into_iter().unzip();
    Ok(())
}
```

This works, however, the chaining of `collect` and `unzip` seems awkward to me, and from my experiments with cargo bench, it is about twice as slow as an imperative equivalent. Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Why not https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb70ebf1b7267b30ff41c8c0c95a92cd ? There is no reason to complicate thing here

Comment: @Stargateur Yeah that looks a lot nicer. The downside is that if i do it that way I need to iterate over the list twice, but only one time is necessary. For example if i do it like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66f15e4e658b971b4f972edcfcbd9c11 it takes 129 ns for a list of 64 elements on my machine, and your solution takes 456 ns.

Comment: did you bench with cargo run --release ?

Comment: Yeah for cargo bench the default is release, but for good measure I have added the following profile to my Cargo.toml:
[profile.bench]
opt-level = 3
lto = true